# Failing to add pod file to Xcode 13 project

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcode13

I am trying to add a pod file to my project but I consistently get this error in the terminal. Does anyone know how to fix this? Or is it because I already use Xcode 13 with iOS 15 beta? My Project is called AdMob testing because I wanted to use Cocoapods for Admob in case you wondered. Thanks.

myName@MacBook AdMob testing % pod init

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

#### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod init
```

#### Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.10.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : macOS 11.5 (20G5023d)
       Xcode : 12.5 (12E262)
         Git : git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

#### Error

```
RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:227:in `initialize_from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:112:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/init.rb:41:in `validate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:333:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=%5BXcodeproj%5D+Unknown+object+version.&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...

- [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version.  Help Please
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10604 [open] [6 comments]
  a week ago
- POD INIT ERROR
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10728 [open] [0 comments]
  2 days ago
- Xcode-beta 13.0 can't init project
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10713 [open] [9 comments]
  3 days ago

and 62 more at:
[https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=%5BXcodeproj%5D%20Unknown%20object%20version.&type=Issues&utf8=✓](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=%5BXcodeproj%5D%20Unknown%20object%20version.&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

**This is the full error. Thanks for ideas.**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Change the project to Xcode 12.0 compatible. Thanks to https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10713#issuecomment-865145924

[image]

Comment: This seemed to solve the problem for me(although I still get a warning: `[!] The version of CocoaPods used to generate the lockfile (1.11.2) is higher than the version of the current executable (1.10.1). Incompatibility issues may arise.` But can anyone comment why/how this solves the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget after changing **Project Format** you also need to update the xcodeproj with:

```
sudo gem update xcodeproj
```

Comment: This worked for me on Xcode 13.2.1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Run the following commands in terminal:

1. `sudo gem update xcodeproj`
2. `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
3. `arch -x86_64 pod install`

It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, that helped:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

and now `pod init` works